# How do I split a huge file into multiple files?

Tags: python, linux, file, unix, memory

What's the easiest way to do this without running out of memory?

I have a 9GB file that has 100 million lines (each is a URL).

How can I split this up into X files?  I tried `for f in fileinput.input('...')`, but it got "killed" for some reason.

Comment: You could just use the [command-line split utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html)...

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import with_statement

YOUR_FILENAME= 'bigfile.log'
SPLIT_NAME= 'bigfile.part%05d.log'
SPLIT_SIZE= 10000 # lines
SPLITTER= lambda t: t[0]//SPLIT_SIZE

import itertools as it

with open(YOUR_FILENAME, "r") as input_file:
    for part_no, lines in it.groupby(enumerate(input_file), SPLITTER):
        with open(SPLIT_NAME % part_no, "w") as out:
             out.writelines(item[1] for item in lines)
```

Store the correct filename as `YOUR_FILENAME`. Decide on how many lines each part will have (`SPLIT_SIZE`). Decide on the output name (`SPLIT_NAME`). Run it. You are not restricted to plain filenames in `YOUR_FILENAME` and `SPLIT_NAME`, obviously; you can use paths.